# Obtener el valor de un columna de un GridView por cada ROW

Tags: vb.net

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor de una columna de un `GridView` debido a que necesito hacer una validación si un campo esta vacio un `checkbox` es igual a `Enable=True`

```
Protected Sub VALIDAR_CheckBox()

    Dim nrAs Integer
    nr= ResultadosBusqueda.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To nr- 1
        Me.GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("Fecha")


    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿GridView o es DataGridView ?

Comment: Como bien pregunta @SilvestreSilva, que tipo de aplicación es? Winforms? Asp? WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un GridView realiza lo siguiente:

```
Protected Sub VALIDAR_CheckBox()

    Dim nr As Integer
    nr= ResultadosBusqueda.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To nr- 1
        'En Cell(0), cambia el número cero por el número de la columna
        If GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text = "" Then
             'Acciones
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ahora, en caso de que tuvieras muchas columnas y/o no supieras el número de la columna, puedes almacenar el número de la columna en una variable.

```
Protected Sub VALIDAR_CheckBox()

    Dim nr As Integer
    nr= ResultadosBusqueda.Rows.Count

    'Declaras la variable
    Dim NumeroDeColumna As Integer

    'Recorres el Gridview para obtener el número de la columna que se llame NombreDeUsuario
    For j As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        If GridView1.Columns.Item(j).HeaderText = "NombreDeUsuario" Then
            NumeroDeColumna = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To nr- 1
        'Utilizas la variable NumeroDeColumna
        If GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(NumeroDeColumna).Text = "" Then
             'Acciones
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```